# Facebook login Oauth dialog on close event?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

On the Facebook JS SDK, I'm trying to detect when a user close the Oauth dialog after clicking on login button (accept or deny), so there is the property onlogin :

```
<div class='fb-login-button" onlogin="function...">FB login</div>
```

**But this method is really bad !** And I don't find any event or indication that I could do this without element property...

The [other events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) related : auth.authResponseChange and auth.statusChange are called at start if user is already connected to the app. And the event auth.prompt is never called (I'm trying to report a bug about this but the [bug report page](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) is bugged...).

So is this script :

```
$('.fb-login-button').each(function() {
    var oldLoginFn = this.onlogin || $.noop();
    this.onlogin = function () {
        //my instructions...
        return oldLoginFn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

is the best I can do to detect the return of Oauth dialog ? there is really no events to detect the login action ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow the URL in which you are running the Facebook JavaScript SDK. TO do this go and edit your facebook app at http://developers.facebook.com/apps under "settings-basic-basic info", put all the URLs on the "App Domains" field e.g www.yourdomain.com, yourdomain.com.

Not that the URLs you put here must be derived from your "Website URL" field below the "Basic Info" settings, under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" - "Website with Facebook Login"

Facebook has logged the error that is being shown when you try running your app when the URL is not allowed. TO view this log go to your browser console and view the logs

Enjoy

Comment: Please re-read my question, I try to find a javascript event to know when the user has clicked on the login button and goes back to the site with successful login.